# Data not loaded when API CALL made using fetch() function in REACTJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have tried to make an apicall with react code and tried to print the response but it shows error
react code

```
    import React,{Component} from 'react'
    
    class ApiCall extends Component 
    {
        constructor(props)
        {
            super(props);
            this.state=
            {
                items:[],
                isloaded:false,
            }
        }
    
        componentDidMount()
        {
            fetch('api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=chennai&appid=e407e5e8......')
            .then(res=>res.json())
            console.log(res.json())
            .then(json=>{
                 this.setState({
                     isloaded:true,
                     items: json,
                 })
            });
        }
    
        render()
        {
            var{isloaded,items}=this.state;
    
            if(!isloaded)
            {
                return <div>Loading..</div>;
            }
            else
            {
            return(
                <div>
                   Data Loaded
                   <ul>
                       {items.map(item=>(
                           <li key={item.id}>
                               Title: {item.title  }
                               Body:{item.body}
                           </li>
                       ))};
                   </ul>
                </div>
            )
            }
        }
    }
    
    export default ApiCall;
```

inside app.js

```
    class App extends Component 
    {
      render()
      {
        return(
          <div className="App">
            <ApiCall/>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
```

**folder structure:
project:
src:
App.js
components:
apicall.js
**

**I got an error in the browser saying,
Failed to compile
src\components\apicall.js
Line 20:21:  'res' is not defined  no-undef**

**Note:The link inside fetch() is taken from openweather website**

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: This is the problem: console.log(res.json()), you can't do this. If you want to console, do inside { }

Comment: I can't understand inside { } means where ?

Comment: `.then(res=>res.json()) console.log(res.json())` to `.then(res=> {res.json(); console.log(res.json())}`

Comment: Got this error when changed like this  Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Failed to execute 'json' on 'Response': body stream already read

Comment: check what is coming from endpoint. If there's html text, you have write your own json parser otherwise you get error if you do .json()

Comment: how to check what is coming from endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

the issue is you are using the `res` outside of the `then` block to solve it add this to the code

```
.then((res) => {
    console.log(res.json());
    return res.json();
 })
```

Comment: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Failed to execute 'json' on 'Response': body stream already read

Comment: I got this error while executed those changes

Comment: this code is working fine when I give another link fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')

Comment: but not working when I give fetch('api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=chennai&appid=e407e5e811a9.......')